# Stadia gamepads & pi4b bullseye bluetooth disconnects

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad

All right,

My setup consist of a RPi 4b 4gb, 4 stadia controllers, Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye.
OS on SSD connected through powered USB3 hub, also a Coral USB connected. Power should be ok.

The controllers connect as expected, and usually stay connected when not is use. They work fine in browser gamepad test. But almost instantly when buttons start flying, the controllers fail. The errors started to occur after update to Bullseye. Using previous version of OS was functioning as inteded - most of the time, but not perfect.

The error patterns:

```
1. Disconnects without reconnect.
2. Disconnects with reconnect after a minute or so
  a) reconnect as inteded
  b) reconnect as another controller, ie taking control of other users' caracters
  c) reconnect as a new controller, not included in game but existing in BT stack.
  d) reconnect as existing and prev controller, controlling two users' caracters at the same time.
```

I have seen that also other Stadia users have had issues with connection, not only with Bullseye, but with Windows, Nintendo Switch, etc. 8bitdo seams to solve the issue platform wide.

What changed with upgrade to Bullseye, and any ideas what I can rollback to remedy?

Thanks a lot for all possible help!

Comment: Does this link help? https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/google-stadia-on-raspberry-pi